# jQuery multiple clearInterval in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear an time interval in jQuery. My problem is that I initialize multiple time intervals in a loop and my clearInterval part is not working correctly.

I have the following ajax function which has a loop for creating multiple timers.

```
function ajax() {
    var form = $('form');
    var timers = [];

    $(form).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', (function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            // shorted ajax code ...
            success: function(data) {
                    var countdown = [];
                    timers = [];
                    i = 0;
                    $.each(data.game.fouls, function(key, fouls) {
                        $.each(fouls, function(number, foul) {
                            var currentFoulsElement = $('#currentFouls');
                            timers[i] = setInterval(function() {
                                countdown = handleFouls(foul, currentFoulsElement, timers[i]);

                                // This line will later occur an error
                                currentFoulsElement.html('Time: ' + countdown.minutes + ":" + countdown.seconds);
                            }, 1000);
                            i++;
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }));
}
```

The next function compares two dates for a later countdown and is responsible for clearing the time interval:

```
function handleFouls(foul, element, timer) {
    var compareDate = new Date(foul.foulTimeJsFormat);

    var now = new Date();
    var difference = compareDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

    if (difference <= 0) {
        // Timer done
        element.empty();
        clearInterval(timer);
        return;
    } else {
        // Some code for vars seconds, minutes ...

        return {
            "seconds": seconds,
            "minutes": minutes
        };
    }
}
```

My browser console prints me following error every second:

> TypeError: countdown is undefined

So my result variable from handleFouls() is not set, but why does it occur when I have already destroyed the specific time interval for that function?

Comment: Which line is that error coming from?

Comment: You don't return anything when the difference is <= 0

Comment: currentFoulsElement.html('Time: ' + countdown.minutes + ":" + countdown.seconds);

Comment: when you return nothing, you get undefined in return..

Comment: The variable `i` is not local to the `.each()` functions, so all the iterations are using the same value. When the interval function runs, it's outside the size of the `timers` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my problem when I clear the Interval in the setInterval function directly.

First I return false in `handleFouls()`

```
if (difference <= 0) {
    // Timer done
    element.empty();
    return false;
} else {
```

And then I look for the result in my set Interval function

```
timers[i] = setInterval(function() {
    var countdown = handleFouls(foul, currentFoulsElement);

    if (!countdown) {
        clearInterval(timers[i]);
        return;
    }

    // Code ...
}, 1000);
```

Thanks for the hints from Andrew Li and Sudhir Bastakoti